# Compute $f(f(1))$ if $f(x)=3x+2$

Tags: functions

Question :

Let the function $f$ be defined by $f(x)=3x+2$.

Then $f(f(1))=$

$f^2(1)$=

and $f^2(f(1))=$

for this first one I replaced the $x$ by $1$ so it gives $5$, the second one $=25$ and $100$ for the last
but I am not sure if it is the right way to resolve it.
Thank you,

Comment: Your answer to the first one is wrong. You want $f(f(1))$, not $f(1)$. Also, I assume the notation $f^2(1)$ means $(f(1))^2$. You got the 2nd one right. Now, are you confused by notation on the third one again? You want $f^2(f(1)) = (f(f(1)))^2$.

Comment: okey thanks, so is it 17?

Comment: yeah I was not sure what the third one meant, so it should be (17)^2

Comment: Is "*it*" $17$?  What "*it*" are you referring to?  There are several "*it*"s you might have been talking about.  Is $f(f(1))$ equal to $17$?  Yes.  $f$ is a function which multiplies the input by three and then adds two... regardless what that input was, however complicated or simple.  $f(1)=3\cdot 1 + 2=5$.  Meanwhile $f(42) = 3\cdot 42 + 2$ and $f(88\sin(x)^2+\pi^{\sqrt{2}}+more) = 3\cdot (88\sin(x)^2+\pi^{\sqrt{2}}+more) + 2$ and $f(f(x)) = 3\cdot f(x)+2$ and so on...

Comment: sorry, if i was not clear enough. so  f(f(1))  equal to 17 and f^2(1) equal to 25 and f^2(f(1)) equals to (17)^2

Comment: As far as the notation $f^2(x)$, some authors do intend this to be functional composition... $f(f(x))$.  Other authors intend this to be exponentiation... $(f(x))^2$.  From context, it seems clear whoever wrote this question intends this to be exponentiation, otherwise $f(f(1))$ and $f^2(1)$ wouldn't both be asked separately.  To avoid such confusion, many authors will avoid the notation entirely and instead write as $f^{\circ 2}(x)$ for functional composition and $(f(x))^2$ with the additional parentheses respectively.

Comment: Note for instance the frustrating notation $\sin^{-1}(x)$... this predominantly in the united states is in reference to the functional inverse of sine.  Meanwhile in Europe, this might instead be interpreted as the multiplicative inverse of sine.  Best to avoid the notation entirely and use the notations $\arcsin(x)$ and $\csc(x)$ instead respectively.  As always, it is best to try to confirm what notation the author/teacher/person you are reading uses as notations can and do vary depending on region.

Comment: Yes, I agree and thank you for the detailed explanation. I will confirm with my teacher. If we take this to be exponentiation, would my answer be correct?

Comment: yes$~~~~~~~~~~$

Answer (score 1):

So starting with $f(x) = 3x + 2$ we can say $f(1) = 3\cdot 1 + 2 = 5$

And because $f(1) = 5$, we can substitute $f(f(1)) = f(5)$

Then $f(5) = 3\cdot 5 + 2 = 17$, therefore $f(5) = f(f(1)) = 17$

And so on, just keep recursively calculating step by step until you've worked your way up the whole chain

Answer (score 0):

if $f(x)=3x+2$ then $f(f(x))=f(3x+2)=3(3x+2)+2=9x+6+2=9x+8$.

So you can calculate $f(f(1))$ in either of two ways:

$$f(f(1))= 9(1)+ 8= 9+ 8= 17$$ or

$$f(1)=  3(1)+ 2= 3+ 2= 5$$ so
$$f(f(1))= f(5)= 3(5)+ 2= 15+ 2= 17.$$